# How to install octave 4.2.0 on my machine?

Tags: debian, software-installation, octave

How can I install Octave 4.2.0 or latest? I have tried:

- [Installing latest version of GNU Octave when I have already installed other version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945517/installing-latest-version-of-gnu-octave-when-i-have-already-installed-other-vers): does not give flathub command not found
- [Installing Octave 4.2.0 from source on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104551/installing-octave-4-2-0-from-source-on-ubuntu): does not work
- [Installing Octave 4.2.0 from source on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104551/installing-octave-4-2-0-from-source-on-ubuntu): does not work configure: `error: BLAS and LAPACK libraries are required`
- [Installing Octave 4.2.0 from source on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104551/installing-octave-4-2-0-from-source-on-ubuntu): not work installed 4.0.3 instead

This is my PC version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:        9.6
Codename:       stretch
```

I ran the command `sudo -i` to enter root then the following commands. I am not sure if it is correct.

```
$ sudo -i
# echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
# apt update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:7 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:9 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/debian9/amd64  InRelease
Hit:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease
Hit:11 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/debian9/amd64  InRelease
Hit:12 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:14 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/debian9/amd64  InRelease
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:1
```

Comment: Please explain why the installation failed. You need to give us more information about your problem. Share the logs of installation.

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave installs 4.0.2 instead of the latest one

Comment: You repeated the same link three times, is that what you intended?

Comment: Note that those PPAs are for Ubuntu. Ubuntu and Debian are different enough that using them on Debian _may_ cause problems. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install Octave 4.4.1 (as of this writing) from [Stretch backports](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch-backports/octave):

1. add the backports repository (as root)

   ```
   echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
   ```
2. update your package indexes

   ```
   apt update
   ```
3. install OpenJDK

   ```
   apt install -t stretch-backports octave
   ```

If you’d rather use `sudo`, the equivalent steps are

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports octave
```