# Trying to install Image package on Octave 4.4.1

Tags: debian, software-installation, octave

I am using the following version of linux.

```
e130167@instance-1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:        9.6
Codename:       stretch
```

I have Octave version 4.4.1 and am trying to install the Image package for Octave https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/index.html. I downloaded the tar.gz file and ran the following command and got an error

```
octave:2> pkg install image-2.8.0.tar.gz
pkg: please install the Debian package "liboctave-dev" to get the mkoctfile command
error: called from
    __gripe_missing_component__ at line 53 column 3
    configure_make at line 44 column 7
    install at line 186 column 7
    pkg at line 437 column 9
octave:2>
```

So I then tried installing liboctave-dev but I now receive this error.

```
e130167@instance-1:~$ sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liboctave-dev : Depends: liboctave3v5 (= 4.0.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: octave (= 4.0.3-3) but 4.4.1-2~bpo9+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you [installed Octave from Stretch backports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481985/117549), you need to install the development package from there too:

```
sudo apt-get install -t stretch-backports liboctave-dev
```